# Google Test - Constructor declaration error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, declaration, googletest, default-constructor

I am trying to create a test fixture class from a normal class with constructor declaration (with arguments) as shown below:

**hello.h**

```
class hello
{
public:
hello(const uint32_t argID, const uint8_t argCommand);
virtual ~hello();
void initialize();
};
```

where uint32_t is: `typedef unsigned int` and uint8_t is: `typedef unsigned char`

My Test Fixture Class:

**helloTestFixture.h**

```
class helloTestFixture:public testing::Test
{
public:
helloTestFixture(/*How to carry out the constructor declaration in this test fixture class corresponding to the above class?*/);
virtual ~helloTestFixture();
hello m_object;
    };
TEST_F(helloTestFixture, InitializeCheck) // Test to access the 'intialize' function
{
m_object.initialize();
}
```

After trying to implement the above code, it gives me the error:

```
 Error C2512: no appropriate default constructor available
```

I was trying to replicate the constructor constructed in the **hello.h** file into my **hellotestfixture.h** file. Any way around for doing that?
I have tried implementing it in many ways but no success as of yet. Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: Can you explain what are using the class hello for? Is this class being tested? I think so. Can you write the code showing how you would like to use the class helloTestFixture in order to test hello?

Comment: Yes, hello is the class being tested and helloTestFixture is its 'TestFixture' class. The problem I am facing here is that, I am unable to initialize the constructor in the Fixture class like the way its done in the actual class and that is exactly my main question. I'll add a test to show how I intend to access the hello class via helloTestFixture.

Comment: But, @Emulator, that's the very problem: you can't provide a constructor with parameters if you plan to use TEST_F. The compiling error has to do with the helloTestFixture class, which does not have a default constructor, and that's what the TEST_F macro needs in order to create an object. If you think about it, it is impossible for TEST_F to create an object of your class if the constructor is not the default one (he cannot know what params to pass). I think you should approach the problem creating the object(s) needed inside the helloTestFixtureClass, as exposed in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After not much of code correction, here's what I've got for you in store: **An Answer** :)

```
class hello
{
public:
  hello(const uint32_t argID, const uint8_t argCommand);
virtual ~hello();
void initialize();
};

hello::hello(const uint32_t argID, const uint8_t argCommand){/* do nothing*/}
hello::~hello(){/* do nothing*/}
void hello::initialize(){/* do nothing*/}

class helloTestFixture
{
public:
  helloTestFixture();
  virtual ~helloTestFixture();
  hello m_object;
};

helloTestFixture::helloTestFixture():m_object(0,0){/* do nothing */}
helloTestFixture::~helloTestFixture(){/* do nothing */}

int main()
{
    helloTestFixture htf;
    htf.m_object.initialize();
}
```

This compiles and runs nicely and hope this answers your question. :)

Answer (score 3):

This error is telling you that you are not providing a default constructor in the `helloTestFixture` class, needed by the `TEST_F` macro in order to create an object of your class.

You should use a *part-of* relationship instead of an *is-a*. Create all objects of the class `hello` you need, in order to test all the various aspects you need.

I am not an expert in Google Test. However, browsing the documentation here:

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#test-fixtures-using-the-same-data-configuration-for-multiple-tests

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#should-i-use-the-constructordestructor-of-the-test-fixture-or-setupteardown

It seems that the `SetUp` method is preferred. If your objective is to test the class `hello`, you could write it this way:

```
#include <memory>

#include "hello.h"
#include "gtest.h"

class TestHello: public testing::Test {
public:
    virtual void SetUp()
    {
        obj1.reset( new hello( /* your args here */ ) );
        obj2.reset( new hello( /* your args here */ ) );
    }

    std::auto_ptr<hello> obj1;
    std::auto_ptr<hello> obj2;
};

TEST_F(QueueTest, MyTestsOverHello) {
    EXPECT_EQ( 0, obj1->... );
    ASSERT_TRUE( obj2->... != NULL);
}
```

`auto_ptr` is not really needed, but it will save you the effort of writing the `TearDown` function, and it also will delete the object in case something goes wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't really work this way. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I'm adding a comment to your question. I'm then quite certain that I don't understand the question itself.